# How to control ASP.NET MVC Route generation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a route like

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        "Reports",                                              // Route name.
        "reports/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{start}/{end}",     // URL with parameters.
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", start="", end="" }  // Parameter defaults.
    );
```

where `start` and `end` are DateTime?

When I write an Html.ActionLink, it generates the route using the `DateTime.ToString` method. Those dates have forward slashes in them which disrupts the route.  I'd like to somehow control the route generation to generate [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date strings.

Ideally I don't want to have to change my Actions to take strings and convert in my code, I'd like to signal the route generator to call the appropriate `ToString` overload of my choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Html.ActionLink`, when you're declaring the start and end values, why not do something like:

```
new{start = String.Format("{0:YYYY-MM-dd}", SomeDate)}
```

or this if you need the time in there too:

```
new{start = String.Format("{0:s}", SomeDate)}
```

Bit of work, but it will guarentee it's formatted correctly.

Comment: You mean `yyyy-MM-dd` (lower-case for year)?